# STM32 SPI: strange behavior on empty TXFIFO (previous bytes history?)

Tags: microcontroller, c, serial, spi, stm32

The following code **configures and enables SPI2 as slave** on my **STM32F303RE board**, writes **0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD** bytes to **DR** register and loops in a **while(1)**:

```
/* Enable clocks for GPIOB (SPI2 pins) and SPI2 peripheral. */
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI2, ENABLE);

/* SPI pin mappings. */
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_5); /* SPI2_NSS */
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_5); /* SPI2_SCK */
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_5); /* SPI2_MISO */
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_5); /* SPI2_MOSI */

GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_init_struct =
{
    .GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF,
    .GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP,
    .GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN,
    .GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz
};

/* SPI NSS pin configuration. */
gpio_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio_init_struct);
/* SPI SCK pin configuration. */
gpio_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio_init_struct);
/* SPI MISO pin configuration. */
gpio_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_14;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio_init_struct);
/* SPI  MOSI pin configuration. */
gpio_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio_init_struct);

SPI_InitTypeDef spi_init_struct =
{
    .SPI_Direction          = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex,
    .SPI_Mode               = SPI_Mode_Slave,
    .SPI_DataSize           = SPI_DataSize_8b,
    .SPI_CPOL               = SPI_CPOL_Low,
    .SPI_CPHA               = SPI_CPHA_1Edge,
    .SPI_NSS                = SPI_NSS_Hard,
    .SPI_BaudRatePrescaler  = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_2,
    .SPI_FirstBit           = SPI_FirstBit_MSB,
    .SPI_CRCPolynomial      = 7
};

SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI2);
SPI_Init(SPI2, &spi_init_struct);
SPI_CalculateCRC(SPI2, DISABLE);
SPI_TIModeCmd(SPI2, DISABLE);
SPI_NSSPulseModeCmd(SPI2, DISABLE);

SPI_Cmd(SPI2, ENABLE);
SPI_SendData8(SPI2, (uint8_t) 0xAA);
SPI_SendData8(SPI2, (uint8_t) 0xBB);
SPI_SendData8(SPI2, (uint8_t) 0xCC);
SPI_SendData8(SPI2, (uint8_t) 0xDD);

while(1) { }
```

With a master that requests **2 bytes per chip-select**, the master receives:

```
0xAA 0xBB
0xCC 0xDD
0xAA 0xAA -----> TXFIFO should be empty here, why not "0x00 0x00"?
0xAA 0xAA
0xAA 0xAA
0xAA 0xAA
0xAA 0xAA
0xAA 0xAA
0xAA 0xAA
......... (0xAA 0xAA infinite times)
```

I would have expected that the master receives **"0x00 0x00" after TXFIFO becomes empty**. Why do I get "**0xAA 0xAA**" continuously instead? I couldn't find something that would point to such behavior in the manual.

**UPDATE 1**

Waiting for the transactions to finish just **before the while(1)** and **writing zeros on the SPI** afterwards, like this:

```
while(SPI_GetTransmissionFIFOStatus(SPI2) != SPI_TransmissionFIFOStatus_Empty) { }
while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY) != RESET) { }

#define ZEROS_CNT   (1)
for(int i = 0; i < ZEROS_CNT; i++)
    SPI_SendData8(SPI2, 0);

while(1) { }
```

renders the following master behavior for different values of ZEROS_CNT:

```
ZEROS_CNT = 0 => master receives after TXFIFO is empty: 0xAA infinitely
ZEROS_CNT = 1 => master receives after TXFIFO is empty: 0x00 1 times, followed by 0xBB infinitely
ZEROS_CNT = 2 => master receives after TXFIFO is empty: 0x00 2 times, followed by 0xCC infinitely
ZEROS_CNT = 3 => master receives after TXFIFO is empty: 0x00 3 times, followed by 0xDD infinitely
ZEROS_CNT >= 4 => master receives after TXFIFO is empty: 0x00 infinitely
```

It looks as if the SPI peripheral has some kind of history of what was written in the TXFIFO and when it becomes empty, it sends bytes from that history.

**UPDATE 2**

It behaves the same irrespective of how many bytes the master requests in a single chip-select. I have tried requesting **1, 2, 4 and 5** @ a time.

Comment: This looks quite odd. Did you try to disable the SPI after sending 0xdd?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, yes, another odd thing is that once disabled, it will send "0x00 0x00" - but if it is re-enabled, it will start sending "0xAA 0xAA" again...two workarounds for this would be either disabling it until I have something new to send -OR- resetting the peripheral entirely (SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI2)). However I'd like to know why it behaves this way (and by what logic) and if I could avoid doing a full-fledged reset (which also requires re-configuring the peripheral - kinda superfluous).

Comment: Would you care adding the link to the relevant appnote/datasheet/whatever? I can't look into it right now but it might be back in my mind tonight.

Comment: You mean the STM32 reference manual? For my STM32F303RE board, here it is: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4a/19/6e/18/9d/92/43/32/DM00043574.pdf/files/DM00043574.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00043574.pdf

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the received data to arrive?

Comment: @domen Please see **UPDATE**

Comment: What? No. Wait on SPI data RX. Fiddling with GPIOs while debugging SPI problem is asking for trouble (and hacky solutions which *might* work).

Comment: I have a logic analyzer, the above works correctly. Change it with waiting on SPI RX (btw, why wait on RX and not until TXFIFO is empty and BSY is not set instead?) and you will see that it behaves the same. :)

Comment: Hi @domen, sorry, I had just turned off my Raspberry Pi 2 (master) earlier and I didn't have time to change the code. Updated the question. As I expected, waiting for TXFIFO to become empty and BSY to be unset renders the same behavior.

Comment: OK. I believe you should wait for empty TXFIFO before every SPI_SendData8. Although to be fair, I'm not sure how this would be related. 0xaa (10101010) looks like clock might be induced on data line. How long are your wires? What's in status registers? I guess it's also just possible it takes a *random* byte when there's nothing new in TX register.

Comment: clock is twice as fast as data, so if (very bad) coupling would occur I'd expect either 0x00 or 0xff, depending on the polarity of the channel.

Comment: @domen They are not random at all. The described experiment should make that clear. Waiting for TXFIFO to be empty after every byte is not an option (defeats the purpose of the FIFO) and it still behaves the same anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out and decided to make this answer more comprehensive by creating some animations. First of all, there are 2 facts to keep in mind that determine the logic behind TXFIFO's behavior:

- As the manual states, TXFIFO is of size **32-bit = 4 bytes** - let those bytes be **B1|B2|B3|B4** in that order.
- **FACT #1**: When the master requests a byte from the slave, the popped and returned byte is **B1** *but* **it isn't actually removed from TXFIFO** ---> the TXFIFO contents are **left-*rotated***, and **not left-*shifted***. This results in TXFIFO looking like **B2|B3|B4|B1** after this pop, **instead of B2|B3|B4|00** (which is I think what @ogrenci meant with his answer).
- **FACT #2**: When TXFIFO becomes empty, for some reason a master request receives the **1st byte that is in TXFIFO @ that moment** instead of **0x00** as I would have expected.

RXFIFO most probably behaves the same way.

The algorithm for both **push/pop**, written in **C#** is as following:

```
public class TXFIFO
{
    public byte[] data;
    byte push_position = 1;
    byte occupied = 0;

    public TXFIFO()
    {
        data = new byte[4];
    }

    public byte Push(byte v)
    {
        // write
        data[push_position - 1] = v;
        // push_position
        if (push_position < 4) push_position++;
        else push_position = 1;
        // occupied
        if (occupied < 4) occupied++;
        return v;
    }

    public byte Pop()
    {
        // read
        if (occupied == 0) return data[0];
        byte v = data[0];
        // rotate left once
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            data[i - 1] = data[i];
        data[3] = v;
        //push_position
        if (push_position > 1) push_position--;
        else push_position = 4;
        //occupied
        if (occupied > 0) occupied--;
        return v;
    }

    public byte GetOccupied()
    {
        return occupied;
    }
}
```

And here are 5 animations that illustrate the originally described **ZEROS_CNT** scenarios (see question's **UPDATE 1**). Note that, to make the point clearer, **instead of inserting zeroes**, I inserted **0x01-0x02-..to..-ZEROS_CNT values** here.

**ZEROS_CNT = 0:**

[image]

**ZEROS_CNT = 1:**

[image]

**ZEROS_CNT = 2:**

[image]

**ZEROS_CNT = 3:**

[image]

**ZEROS_CNT = 4:**

[image]

**ZEROS_CNT = 5:**

[image]

...and so on...

As previously mentioned in the question, a workaround for having **0x00** sent when TXFIFO is empty would be keeping the **SPI** peripheral **disabled** when TXFIFO is empty until new data is written in **DR**, which is what I ended up doing, after understanding what is going on.

Comment: In fact, the data is probably not really copied around in the buffer but two indexes are maintained for the start and end of the buffered data. When start and end point to the same element of the buffer, that can mean either of two things: Either the buffer is completely full, or it is completely empty. No way to determine which one it is without maintaining another flag somewhere. See [Circular Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: @m.Alin thanks! I hope they make things clearer. JimmyB not sure what you're trying to say - the SPI **does** retain information telling you what the current occupancy level of the FIFOs are..

Comment: @JimmyB ooh, I understand. Yes, you're most probably right. It would be too inefficient to keep shifting elements to the left when doing a pop. Anyway, I think the results of pop/push operations above would render the same values. I guess one could try and understand how that shift schematic in the SPI block diagram actually works @ electronic level to really find out how these operations are done internally (the data structure used).

Comment: Just wanted to provide a simple explanation as to why a certain element seems to remain in the buffer. Indeed, if the device knows when the buffer is empty, the SPI circuitry could/should use that bit of information to provide consistent output (0x00) instead of "random" garbage.

Comment: @JimmyB yes, thank you for the input and sorry, I didn't understand what you were trying to suggest the first time ;)

Comment: Silly question: what did you use for the animations?

Comment: Hi @pgvoorhees. Nothing special actually, just a little bit of C# (my TXFIFO class has a Draw method returning a Bitmap instance on which it drew its state (see Bitmap and Graphics classes). I'd construct a scenario (pushes/pops sequence) and call Draw after each operation. Saved the bitmaps in image files and used http://gifcreator.me/ to create the GIFs. But most probably there are better tools to do this instead of reinventing the wheel, I just didn't have the disposition to search for them, as I had other work to do.

Answer (score 0):

The values after 4th byte are not sourced from TX buffer of slave. Examine the SPI block diagram. They are originally sent as dump data by master when the SCI is cycled and they return from the shift register of slave and appear as valid data. When master pulls data, that is what expected to be overridden, but doesn't in this case because slave doesn't push data into TX buffer and get the shift register loaded.

Comment: Hi ogrenci, did you mean "sent as dump data when the SPI is cycled by Raspberry PI"?

Comment: Hi @CorneliuZuzu. I mean Raspberry PI. I edited the answer.